# Duplicate documents with same unique key

Tags: java, solr

For a particular Solr application, I need to have duplicate results discarded. I have a field `id` set as a unique key in schema.xml as such:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

When I call `/update/json?commit=true` with the id of an existing document, the extant document is properly updated. However, when I call `/update/json?commit=true&overwrite=false` then an additional document is added with the same id! **How can I configure Solr to discard documents which have the id of an existing document?** I notice that [the `allowDups` attribute is depreciated](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22), so I do not want to introduce it into new code running Solr 4.x. In any case, the default is `false` so I do not see why the dupe is being added anyway.

If it matters, the `id` field is defined as such:

```
<field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
```

To be clear, I do not want to update, and I do not want to create a new document. **I want to *discard* the new document.** The `id` field is calculated as a hash of the content of several other fields. So if another field with this same hash (id) already exists, I do *not* want to update it (I need to always keep the oldest doc of the same hash) and I do *not* want to create a new record (dupe). I simply want to discard the new doc.

I am looking for behaviour analogous to an `INSERT IGNORE INTO` SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is due to using overwrite=false. You are explicitly asking for the behavior you are seeing.

This is documented here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates

"Indicates if the unique key constraints should be checked to overwrite previous versions of the same document"

So, if overwrite is "true", CHECK to see if this is overwriting an existing document and delete it, if there is an existing document. If overwrite is false, don't check, just assume this document is unique, and just add the new one.

This would be clearer, if the parameter were named "overwriteCheck" since that's really what it does.

Comment: Thank you. I see from rereading the question that my intention was not clear. I've edited the question to clarify: I need the new doc to be _discarded_ if it is a dupe, similar to `INSERT IGNORE INTO`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Solr Document Deduplication Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) that can be configured on the Update Handler to properly handle this scenario for you.